# adb protocol failure using install and push

Tags: android, installation, push, protocols, adb

I cannot install apk files to my phone using adb install.
I cannot push apk files to my phone's sdcard using adb push.
In both cases adb gives me "protocol failure", followed by a notice that it is unable to delete the apk file from data/local/tmp (which I'm pretty sure has to do with the fact that it's unable to get the apk file into the phone in the first place).

> protocol failure
>
> rm failed for /data/local/tmp/.apk, No such file or directory

The same goes for AVDs. I've tried four separate emulators to no avail.

USB debugging on the phone is enable.
I'm using the latest version of the OS and the SDK.
The phone is online according to adb devices.
I've made sure there are no adb zombies.

The problem is likely related to my computer's lack of USB write permission, though I am still uncertain because the emulator also gets the protocol failure message.

I'm wondering if there is another way of installing apk files besides using the command line. More specifically, how is eclipse installing the apk files. I am able to deploy to both the emulator and my S4 using eclipse, which seems to bypass USB write permission checks.

Answer (score 8):

1. Push the apk package to the sdcard:

   `adb push test.apk /sdcard/`
2. Install apk from the sdcard:

   `adb shell pm install /sdcard/test.apk`

Comment: It works this way. Do you know why? Can it works with adb install?